# Magnetic field in two different medium

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

From Faraday's law of induction we know if we have a coil with ac current it will create ac current to other coil placed within magnetic field. My question is if one coil is in water and another coil is in air what will be the pattern of magnetic field?

Comment: Please give exact configuration you are considering.

Comment: How big will be your coils? With a distance of 1.5 m between them it may be than even in air your power transmission will be very poor. Are you sure you get something without the water, to start with?

Answer (score 1):

To a very good approximation it will be the same as if both coils were in the same material since water is not very magnetic ( $\frac{\mu}{\mu_0}=0.999992$ ) source: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)).

However if you really care about the slight deviations of the magnetic field's shape then you could apply the appropriate electric and magnetic boundary conditions to the magnetic field to find out how much it deviates. The exact field shape will depend on the position of the interface between water and air and the shape of that interface (i.e. if it's really flat or if the water has waves) As well as the size and shape of the coils.

Comment: That does not answer this question. That could be commented.

Comment: "That does not answer this question." How doesn't it? "That could be commented." No it can't, it's literally too long. 

I can't literally give the exact shape of the magnetic field, if that was what you're going for, unless he gives me an exact problem, as I said. This is as much of an answer as can be, unless you have specific suggestions for more material to include.

Comment: You must ask OP for , " unless he gives
me an exact problem", exact problem.

Comment: ? I must do no such thing. People ask general questions here all the time. If he wants to be more specific, he can be, and may try to make my answer more specific. Until then, how is it harmful to answer what his question *currently* asks?

Comment: This seems a reasonable answer to the question as asked. A more detailed answer would require the question to be clarified.

Comment: But in the following paper in fig:6 the author says, magnetic field will be reflected back. here is the paper "Channel Modeling of MI Underwater Communication
using Tri-directional Coil Antenna" by Hongzhi Guo

Comment: Yeah, there will be reflections as well, but mostly only at angles that are shallow to the surface. I'm not sure what you are looking for, in order to give a detailed antenna pattern, you'd need to give an exact configuration. If you want to do some serious calculations for stuff like that I'd start looking through graduate level physics E&M texts like Jackson or Zangwill. Perhaps some electrical engineering books would be better though. I know Jackson has an interesting problem regarding the reflection of Radio E&M waves off the ionosphere.

Comment: Actually what I want do is something like this. A transmitting 1D coil will be placed just 1m below the water surface and there will be a receiving coil just 0.5m above water surface. At first I thought it is possible because I know there is a slight difference in μ . But after reading above paper I am confused.